# Upsert Attachment object

Tags: soap-api, attachment, upsert

When upserting the fields of Attachment such as Name, upsert works while upserting body like:

```
SObject upsertDoc1 = new SObject("Attachment");
            upsertDoc1.setField("Name", "dummyattach_gloria.txt");
            upsertDoc1.setField("ID", "00P1a000000FrAAACA0");
            upsertDoc1.setField("Body", "aHR0cDovL3N0bGFiLmFkb2JlLmNvbS93aWtpL2ltYWdlcy9kL2QzL1Rlc3QucGRm");
```

The upsert fails with the error:

```
The Upsert failed because: Body: value not of required type: aHR0cDovL3N0bGFiLmFkb2JlLmNvbS93aWtpL2ltYWdlcy9kL2QzL1Rlc3QucGRm
```

This is a Base64 field. How do I deal with this kind of update? Additionally, should I also be updating the BodyLength or will it be handled automatically?

Thanks.

Comment: If you also set the "ContentType" to "text/plain" does it still fail? I notice that the base64 decodes to the text "http://stlab.adobe.com/wiki/images/d/d3/Test.pdf".

Comment: Yes, still fails. I don't think this is an issue with the other fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should pass a byte [] as the value to setField, not the base64 encoded value, the SOAP client will automatically encode it for you.